# Hide table rows based on date AND click a button to show them again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, toggle, hide

With help from this forum I created a table which hides groups of rows based on the current date. Which is great. I am now looking to combine this with a toggle button that shows the hidden dates. But with my very limited knowledge of Javascript I cannot get it done. Any ideas? This is what I have so far:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.event_display_table tbody').each(function(index, element) {
        event_day = $(this).attr('data-date');
        event_day = new Date(event_day);
        today = new Date();
        if(event_day.getTime() < today.getTime())
        { 
           $(this).css('display','none');
        }

        console.log($(this).attr('data-date'));

    });
});

</script>
</head>
```

And for the body:

```
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph which can be hidden by clicking the button.</p>

<button>Toggle between slide up and slide down for a p element, but I want it to toggle 'show previous/hidden' dates</button>

<p>This table below shows only event dates in the future. Which is what I want. But I also want to have a toggle button option which does show the previous events. Is this possible?</p>

<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="event_display_table"  border="1" >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Event</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody data-date="2018-03-13">
               <tr>
                <td>2018-03-13</td>
                <td>My event detail 1</td>
              </tr>                  
               <tr>
                <td>2018-05-14</td>
                <td>My event detail 2</td>
              </tr>
</tbody>                  
<tbody data-date="2018-05-13">
                <tr>
                <td>2018-05-13</td>
                <td>My event detail 3</td>
              </tr>                  
</tbody>
<tbody data-date="2018-05-15">
                <tr>
                <td>2018-05-15</td>
                <td>My event detail 4</td>
              </tr>                  
              <tr>
                <td>2018-06-27</td>
                <td>My event detail 5</td>
              </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody data-date="2018-06-15">
              <tr>
                <td>2018-06-15</td>
                <td>My event detail 6</td>
              </tr>                  
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the processing function to add a `.in-past` class to every `<tbody>` which has date's in the past. Those date's then can be hidden or shown based on the class of the table. Here's a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $('.event_display_table').toggleClass('future-only');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.event_display_table tbody').each(function(index, element) {
    var event_day = $(this).data('date');
    event_day = new Date(event_day);
    today = new Date();
    if (event_day.getTime() < today.getTime()) {
      $(this).addClass('in-past');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.event_display_table.future-only .in-past {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph which can be hidden by clicking the button.</p>

<button>Toggle between slide up and slide down for a p element, but I want it to toggle 'show previous/hidden' dates</button>

<p>This table below shows only event dates in the future. Which is what I want. But I also want to have a toggle button option which does show the previous events. Is this possible?</p>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="event_display_table future-only" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Event</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-date="2018-03-13">
      <tr>
        <td>2018-03-13</td>
        <td>My event detail 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2018-05-14</td>
        <td>My event detail 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-date="2018-05-13">
      <tr>
        <td>2018-05-13</td>
        <td>My event detail 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-date="2118-05-15">
      <tr>
        <td>2018-05-15</td>
        <td>My event detail 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2118-06-27</td>
        <td>My event detail 5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-date="2018-06-15">
      <tr>
        <td>2018-06-15</td>
        <td>My event detail 6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I can't get a functioning html doc with your code. While I see it works when I press 'run code snippet', I am still doing something wrong. I might seem that your solution is beter suited for my purposes though. It is vital that the date of today is shown. I want so show a sports schedule with like 12 rows (games) on 1 date, and optional show a whole week before the current date to also not hide the scores of last week by default.

Comment: Fixed it by opening the Chrome help for developers. I used the style tags wrong. Sorry 'bout that. So thanks you for helping me address my problem! With this solution I can show the dates of today and optional the rows of games 7 days ago by specifying the 'data-date' 8 days ahead. Fantastic!

Comment: I'm glad your problem is resolved. Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the answer that helped you the most to close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to restructure your HTML table to make the appropriate js work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
        $('.hidden').toggle()
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.event_display_table tbody tr td:first-child').each(function(index, element) {
        var event_day = $(this).text();
        event_day = new Date(event_day);

        // I added this which will set the time of "event_day" to 00:00:00
        event_day.setHours(0,0,0,0)

        var today = new Date();

        // I added this which will set the time of "today" to 00:00:00 
        today.setHours(0,0,0,0)

        if(event_day < today) {
           $(this).parent().hide()
           $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Edited HTML:

```
  <table class="event_display_table"  border="1" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Event</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>2018-03-13</td>
        <td>My event detail 1</td>
      </tr>                  
       <tr>
        <td>2018-05-14</td>
        <td>My event detail 2</td>
      </tr>


        <tr>
        <td>2018-05-13</td>
        <td>My event detail 3</td>
      </tr>                  


        <tr>
        <td>2018-05-15</td>
        <td>My event detail 4</td>
      </tr>                  
      <tr>
        <td>2018-06-27</td>
        <td>My event detail 5</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>2018-06-15</td>
        <td>My event detail 6</td>
      </tr>                  
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Wow, this is so cool! It works like a charm, but in this way it creates an additional problem for me: it is for my purposes vital that the date of today is shown. I want so show a sports schedule with like 12 rows (games) on 1 date. With my first solution I could 'fake' the date by specifying the data-date="2018-05-13" as a day before, or even show a whole week before the current date to also not hide the scores of last week.

This is not such an elegant solution as yours, of course. But with your solution, could something like this be done?

Comment: Thank you very much! You inspire me to dive into coding and try out different variables. Very nice

Comment: Glad to hear, please remember to upvote and mark as answer if it solved your problem :)